# Do I add both the new variable and the original variable to my log binomial model?

Tags: modeling, binomial-distribution, logarithm

I'm calculating interaction indices for some variables in my model. I have an interaction between  two variables (age (continuous) and hypertension (binary)), and I read in a similar publication that they evaluated the effect of age per 5 years increase by dividing age by 5, and included this variable in the model.

I would like to do the same, but I'm unsure if I add both the original age variable, and this new variable (age divided by 5), to my model.

Comment: You haven't described any "centered" variables.  So far, you have specified only two variables: hypertension and age, where age is measured either in years or in five-year increments--but's still the same variable, whatever the units of measurement might be.  What, then, do you mean by "centered" and how does it apply in this circumstance?

Comment: Sorry - I was under the impression that centering a variable meant subtracting/dividing, etc., a constant (e.g., 5 years) from that variable.

Comment: "Centering" means subtracting a constant to make some measure of centrality (usually the arithmetic mean or median) equal to zero.

Comment: What does your response variable look like?

Comment: It's a binary outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use only one or the other (unscaled or scaled).  If you try to include them both, they'll be perfectly collinear and will mess up your regression model (meaning "regression" in the most general sense).

As mentioned in comments, scaling your variables will affect the estimated parameter values, and their interpretation (e.g. "change in log-odds of response per 5 years of age" rather than "change in log-odds of response per year of age"), but won't change the overall fit of the model, and won't change inference on the parameters (e.g. Z-statistics, p-values).

If you *center* variables, it still won't change the overall model fit, but it might change the interpretation of the main effects.

Schielzeth, Holger. “Simple Means to Improve the Interpretability of Regression Coefficients.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 1 (2010): 103–13. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00012.x.